# My relational database tables will not link (kivy)

Tags: python, sqlite, kivy

I am making an app using kivy and cannot find out why the two tables I have created won't link up. I want the UserDetailsID from the UserDetails table to appear in my User table.

Can anyone figure out what I've done wrong? The code works fine but doesn't do what I want it to. Any help is highly appreciated!

**Database.py code:**

```
import sqlite3

def create_table(db_name,table_name,sql):

    with sqlite3.connect(db_name) as db:

        cursor = db.cursor()

        cursor.execute("PRAGMA foreign_keys")

        cursor.execute(sql)

        db.commit()


def create_user_table():

    sql = """create table User

             (UserID integer,

             username text,

             password text,

             UserDetailsID integer,

             primary key(UserID),

             foreign key(UserDetailsID) references 

UserDetails(UserDetailsID))"""

    create_table(db_name,"User",sql)


def create_user_details_table():

    sql = """create table UserDetails

            (UserDetailsID integer,

            age text, gender text,

            weight text, height text,

            activity text, target text,

            primary key(UserDetailsID))"""

    create_table(db_name,"UserDetails",sql)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    db_name = "app.db"

    create_user_table()

    create_user_details_table()
```

**Main.py code:**

```
from kivy.app import App

from kivy.uix.button import Button

from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout

from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput

from kivy.lang import Builder

from kivy.uix.image import Image

from kivy.graphics import Rectangle, Color

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen

from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen, FadeTransition

from kivy.core.text import Label

import sqlite3


Builder.load_file('LoginScreen.kv')

Builder.load_file('SignUpScreen.kv')

Builder.load_file('CalorieCalcScreen.kv')

Builder.load_file('HomeScreen.kv')


sm = ScreenManager()


class LoginScreen(Screen):

    def returnback(self):

        self.parent.current = 'calories'

    pass


class SignUpScreen(Screen):

    def CalorieCalcScreen(self,username,password):

        validate = insert_User_data(self,username,password)

        if validate == True:

            sm.add_widget(CalorieCalcScreen(name='done'))

            self.parent.current = 'done'

    pass


class CalorieCalcScreen(Screen):

    def LoginScreen(self,gender,age,weight,height,activity,target):

        validated = 
insert_UserDetails_data(self,age,gender,weight,height,activity,target)

        if validated == True:

            sm.add_widget(LoginScreen(name='finished'))

            self.parent.current = 'finished'

    def returnback(self):

        self.parent.current = 'login'

    pass


class HomeScreen(Screen):

    pass


def insert_User_data(self,username,password):

    with sqlite3.connect(db_name) as db:

        cursor = db.cursor()

        sql = "insert into User(username,password) values (?,?)"

        values = (username,password)

        cursor.execute(sql,values)

        db.commit()


        validate = True

        return validate


def insert_UserDetails_data(self,age,gender,height,weight,activity,target):

    with sqlite3.connect(db_name) as db:

        cursor = db.cursor()

        sql = "insert into UserDetails(age,gender,weight,height,activity,target) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)"

        values = (age,gender,weight,height,activity,target)

        cursor.execute(sql,values)

        db.commit()


        validated = True

        return validated


sm.add_widget(LoginScreen(name='LoginScreen'))

sm.add_widget(SignUpScreen(name='SignUpScreen'))

sm.add_widget(CalorieCalcScreen(name='CalorieCalcScreen'))

sm.add_widget(HomeScreen(name='HomeScreen'))


class MainApp(App):

    def build(self):

        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":

    db_name = "app.db"

    MainApp().run()
```

Comment: After create_table() I have put db.commit() already, what do you mean? @KeyWeeUsr

Comment: sorry, I missed the line. :/